# Dont find weblogic 9.2 installer in edelivery or any other site

Tags: weblogic9.x

I need to install weblogic 9.2 to test a particular web application. Dont find the installer in oracles edelivery or any other site. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

As of December 4, 2012, the BEA Release Archive has been decommissioned. Customers looking for a BEA release that is not available on the Oracle Software Delivery Cloud, or OTN, please refer to MOS Document 1071023.1 'Requesting Physical Shipment or Download URL for Software Media'.

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=464049562271256&id=763603.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=h3iccxrvr_4